# Python code, not able to write into xls

Tags: python, python-3.5

When the below code is executed in Python 3.5 and xlwt 1.2.0, following error is generated:
`"Cannot convert byte objects to str implicitly"`
The code works fine for python 2.7.
Anyone please let me know what could be the problem.
Thanks in Advance!!

```
    import xlwt
    import re
    import os

    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')
    ws_1 = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet_B')
    cnt_row = 0
    cnt_col_1 = 0
    cnt_col_2 = 0


    path = "E:\Python_Scripts"
    files = os.listdir("E:\Python_Scripts")
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".ptu"):
            fo = open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r')

            while(1):
                str = fo.readline()
                if (str == ""):
                    print ("file finished")
                    break
                else:
                    matchObj = re.match(r'\s*  TEST (.*?).*', str)
                    if (matchObj):
                        str = str.split('TEST', 1)[1]
                        ws.write(cnt_row, 0, str)
                        matchObj_Author = re.match(r' (.*)  Author (.*?).*', str)
                    if (matchObj_Author):
                        str = str.split('(', 1)[1]
                        str = str.rsplit(')', 1)
                        ws.write(cnt_row, 1, str)
                        cnt_row = cnt_row + 1

            fo.close()
   wb.save('example.xls')
```

Comment: full stacktrace please...

Comment: I do not have full error info wright now, the problem is at last line, wb.save('example.xls') ....

Comment: are you sure your xlwt version is the one matching python 3? how did you perform the installation?

Comment: yeah,xlwt 1.2.0 is used on python 3.5.did it through downloaded setup.py file.As i was getting connction time out  error through pip command.

Comment: did you run this through 2to3?

Comment: yes,i wrote this code n ran in 2.7,and in other system wanted to use this file which has 3.The problem is in python 3.

Comment: btw don't use `str` as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Your data input has changed. And one or more of its lines contain multiple strings.

If you're reading a file where a line has multiple entires then your str will be a list not a string. If it is a list, this will cause the error when invoking wb.save('example.xls'): `TypeError: must be str, not bytes`

Here's a pared down version of your program that I used to test this out:

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')
ws_1 = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet_B')
cnt_row = 0
cnt_col_1 = 0
cnt_col_2 = 0

f = open('<an xml file with one string per line except the last line which has two strings', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
while 1:

    str = f.readline()
    wb.save('example.xls')
    if str == "":
        print ("file finished")
        break
    str = str.split('<', 1)[1]
    str = str.rsplit('<', 1)
    ws.write(cnt_row, 1, str)
    cnt_row = cnt_row + 1
    print('debug:last')
    print(str)
    print(type(str))

wb.save('example.xls')
f.close()
```

Comment: I don't think that `str` is a list at any moment in the OP code

Comment: @Jean in the OP's code, what about `str = str.rsplit(')', 1)`?

Comment: Thank you all for your sugesstions. I removed 3.5 and installed 2.7,it is working.