# Python 3 - xlwt save Workbook error

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlwt, unicode-string

I'm writing a small program in Python 3.6 that reads an excel file and then modifies the format of a cell. I want multiple formats within the same cell so I'm using `xlwt` with `write_rich_text`:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy

col = 0
row = 0

rb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls', formatting_info=True)

r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0) 
text_cell = r_sheet.cell_value(row, col)

book = copy(rb)
first_sheet = book.get_sheet(0)

font1 = xlwt.easyfont('struck_out true, color_index red')
font2 = xlwt.easyfont('color_index green')

seg1 = (text_cell[0:10], font1)
seg2 = (text_cell[10:], font2)


first_sheet.write_rich_text(row, col, [seg1, seg2])

book.save('test.xls')
```

Everything works fine up to the point of writing on to the excel file but then I get the error `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` when saving the Workbook.

Full error:

```
File "test.py", line 91, in <module>
book.save('test.xls')

File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 710, in save
doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())

File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 674, in get_biff_data
shared_str_table   = self.__sst_rec()

File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 636, in __sst_rec
return self.__sst.get_biff_record()

File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 79, in get_biff_record
self._add_rt_to_sst(s)

File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 108, in _add_rt_to_sst
rt_str, rt_fr = upack2rt(rt, self.encoding)

File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\xlwt\UnicodeUtils.py", line 86, in upack2rt
fr += pack('<HH', offset, fontx)

TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

I've been searching for a solution to this problem but the answers there don't seem to solve my problem:

[xlwt book.save TypeError: must be str, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725686/xlwt-book-save-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes)

[Python code, not able to write into xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616591/python-code-not-able-to-write-into-xls)

Then I found that this issue could be related to the way strings are handled in Python 3 vs Python 2 and that I might be getting a byte string somewhere that is causing the error.

I looked at the type of `text_cell` and is `str`, I tried ommiting the font in `seg1` and `seg2` but it still didn't work.
Finally I ran this same script on Python 2.7 and it worked!

The bad news is that I need the code to work in Python 3 since the server where this would run only has Python 3 and cannot be changed.

Anyone has a clue of what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Javier, your "edit" should be an "answer" instead :) You're allowed to answer your own question here on StackOverflow!

Comment: I didn't know! Thanks

Comment: No worries! You're also allowed to mark your answer as Accepted. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is a know issue in xlwt that was fixed last month! I updated the package and now it works like a charm.

https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/issues/89

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue more than a year later
using `(fake.address().split('\n'))[1].split(',')` from faker as my input, it looks like this error also occurs when you try to input a list (in my case a list of two strings) into a single cell.

Try splitting them up, in my case, the following should work:

```
temp =(fake.address().split('\n'))[1].split(',')
input = temp[0] + temp[1]
sheet.write(0, 0, input)
```

To be more generic, **try concatenating your strings if this is happening to you.**